# Embedding HTML FIle Content In PowerBI

Tags: html, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I have a HTML file , I want to embed this into power BI, how to achieve this. I did tried using custom HTML Content viewer but with no Success.
Some of the link that I tried but with no success https://youtu.be/syzA3PZx3qk, https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Embedding-a-html-site-in-the-Power-BI-Dashbord/m-p/246595

Answer (score 0):

Create one web Server and uplaod HTML file on that server.
then Use HTML as described on youtube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syzA3PZx3qk